# Filter by the sum of two cells

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say we have some data in a spreadsheet like:

```
  A         B          C
Price    Quantity    Genre
 20        2500       Car   
 10        1000       Car
 10        2500       Bike
```

I can filter `Cars` with `Quantity` `2500` with `FILTER(A:A;B:B=2500;C:C="Car")` - easy.

But what if there is another column, for `Postage`, like:

```
  A         B          C         D
Price    Quantity    Genre    Postage
 20        2500       Car       0
 10        1000       Car       6
 10        2500       Bike      10
```

I want to filter to find everything whose total price (`Postage`+`Price`) is `20`, and I have `2500` of. I tried various combinations but can't seem to do it.

Should I create a sum column first?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula to accomplish that.

I used the following dataset:
[image]

Take notice of the extra ID I added.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA!B1:F4, "SELECT F, D WHERE B+E>=20 AND C=2500")
```

### Explained

The two `WHERE` clauses will set the criteria:

- Column C to 2500
- The result of the summation of column B + E to be larger or equal than 20

Column F and D are there to categorise the result.

### Result

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Filter by the sum of two cells in Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGdLSGcydTRsdVp5VzV2RXppb2VCWEE&usp=sharing)**